# How to prevent appending multiple times in the table, Once It forcing to double click multiple times the table row using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have module appending the result of response to the other table. looking forward I found a solution in my module. however I found problem on that i will give to you guys the scenario what the problem it does.

**First Scenario**:
 User will choose what condiment he wanted to click, Looking forward Ex. User 1 choose the Second table row, the Condiments ***LG FRIES**.

[image: first scene]

**Second Scenario**:
 In the first scenario user choose the ***LG FRIES**, as you can see here modal will open and the result of response will append to the table B.

[image: second scene]

**Third Scenario**: Well First and Second scenario look works and good, but here I will show you, how does appending will multiply in the table once i force double click the table row of ***LG FRIES**.

[image: third scene]

**So now i will let you show my codes.**

This is my function for getting the result of clicking the of table row then the result will append to the table B.

```
$('table#noun_chaining_order').on('click','tr.editCondiments',function(e){



    var allow_to_open_condiments_conditional =  $(this).closest("tr").find(".allow_to_open_condiments_conditional").text();


    if(allow_to_open_condiments_conditional == 'Yes') {

        $('.conditional_table_hidden_noun').hide();

        $('.conditional_table_hidden_condiments').show();

        $('table#noun_chaining_order tr').removeClass('selected');

        $(this).addClass('selected');



        var find_each_id_condiments = $(this).find('td.condi_section_id').text();
         $("table#customer_table_update_chain_order tbody").html('');

        $('#customer_modal_update_chain_order').modal('show');

         $.ajax({
          url:'/get_each_id_section_condiments',
          type:'get',
          data:{find_each_id_condiments:find_each_id_condiments},
          success:function(response){

            var get_each_section = response[0].condiments_table;


            $.each(get_each_section, function (index, el) {

               var stringify = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));


              var cat_condi_screen_name = stringify['cat_condi_screen_name'];
              var cat_condi_price = stringify['cat_condi_price'];
              var cat_condi_image = stringify['cat_condi_image'];
              var image = '<img src=/storage/' + cat_condi_image + ' class="responsive-img" style="width:100px;">';

              // $('#edit_chainingBuild').append("<tr class='clickable-row'><td>" + Qty + "</td><td class='clickable-row-condiments'>" + Condiments + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td><td style='display:none;' data-attribute-chain-id="+menu_builder_details_id +" class='data-attribute-chain-id'>"+menu_builder_details_id+"</td></tr>");

              $('table#customer_table_update_chain_order tbody').append("<tr class='edit_condimentsClicked' style='font-size:14px; border:none;'><td class='edit_condimentsScreenNameClicked'>" + cat_condi_screen_name + "</td><td class='edit_condimentsScreenPriced'>" + cat_condi_price + "</td><td>"+image+"</td></tr>");

            });



          },
          error:function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

    }
    else
    {

    }

});
```

**So the question will be, How to stop appending multiple times once I force double click the table row?**

Comment: From what I see here I can not see the problem. Could you show us the response from your ajax request (in Chrome [Right Click] -> Inspect  -> Network.
And try to put your "clean table code" in the success function

Comment: I already try to console my success function once i clicked multiple times, the response also give multiple, if i clicked once It workes find.

Comment: You want to clear earlier table data ?

Comment: yes.. my works find if i clicked once, but when  force to clicked multiple times, then it will append multiple times in the table

Comment: well yes sure because you probably add the data to a database when you click on the add button. So the same date is stored multiple times in you database. Thats why it would be helpful to see what the response to you ajax call is. Or a screenshoot of your database table would also be useful.

Comment: hi @marcramser i will update my post, I will screenshot the response result.

Comment: please see the new update

Comment: We need the "Network" tab not the "Console" one.  Or to me more specific click on the "Network" tab (reload the page with pressing the button "F5", then click on "XHR", then on the "/get_each_id_section_condiments" request and then on "Response" that is what we would need.

Comment: @marcramser sure i will, sorry for the delay message..

Comment: take a look my update

Comment: the thing on the right of your screenshoot (after you have selected the "Response" tab

Answer (score 0):

I see simple solutions here.

1. When you appending cart item, you can add that item ID from database
   to the element. And before appending check if an item from response
   doesn't exist in BODY.
2. Another solution will be just after you click append - hide that CTA
       (button)to prevent it from another click.
3. Check your database for multiple records.

Anyways, please check when you do ajax request? after click?

Have you tried to debug your code with breakpoints? or console?

Comment: Hi Aivaras, I have no problem with my database, seems i have problem to my function, which when i force clicked manytimes the append duplicate many times also

Comment: Hey. Have you tried other solution from my list? How does it go? ;)

Comment: Then please add more JS code. I need to understand were you requesting AJAX.

Comment: ok i will replace all the content, so it will better more understanable.